# how to convert a sql server store procedure to mysql procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to convert store procedure from that is written in sql server, to mysql procedure. I know the their general differences like AS, GO and ; but still mysql procedure has not the same result as sql server. It is noteworthy that tables and their data are the same. can anyone say other differences between them?
I will thank you if you tell me correct answer in this case

Comment: What if you cast to the same type DECIMAL(10,6) in the sql server version?

Comment: i used FLOAT but it did not change

Comment: Sample data, expected results and actual results are necessary here. `float` isn't going to be very accurate for most calculations, perhaps use a more precise data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out for using mysql parameters like `IN b INT` in procedure code, I must use b directly! not @b like sql server